# Are the solutions bounded for every $t ≥ 0$ for this Bernouli Equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following initial value problem.

$$ \begin{cases}
y'=y+y^3,\ t>0 \\
y(0)= \frac{1}{2}
\end{cases} $$

Consider whether their solutions remain bounded for every $t ≥ 0$. If not, you can
determine the 'burst time'.

**Solution**

I Solved the separable equation $\dfrac{dy(t)}{dt} = y(t)^3 + y(t)$, such that $y(0) = \frac{1}{2}$:

Divided both sides by $y^{3}(t) + y(t)$:
$$\frac{\frac{dy(t)}{dt}}{y(t)^3 + y(t)} = 1$$
Integrated both sides with respect to $t$:
$$ \int \frac{\frac{dy(t)}{dt}}{y(t)^3 + y(t)} \, dt = \int 1 \, dt$$

Evaluated the integrals:
$$-\frac{1}{2} \ \log(y(t)^2 + 1) + \log(y(t)) = t + c_1,$$ where $c_1$ is an arbitrary constant.

Solve for $y(t)$:
$$y(t) = -\frac{i e^{t + c_1}}{\sqrt{e^{2 (t + c_1)} - 1}}$$ or
$$y(t) =\frac{i e^{t + c_1}}{ \sqrt{e^{2 (t + c_1)} - 1}}$$

Then I solved these two cases for the initial condition $y(0) = \frac{1}{2}$ and I have found that
$$y(t) = \frac{i e^{t}}{\sqrt{e^{2 t } - 5}}$$

How could I prove the solutions remain bounded for every $t ≥ 0$. If not, you can
determine the 'burst time'?

Comment: Just curious, how is this related to bernoulli equation which says pressure + Energy = constant ?

Comment: As $t > 0$, we have $y(t) = \frac{i}{\sqrt{1-5 e^{-2t}}} \leq constant$, for $ t \notin [\log(5)/2-\epsilon,\log(5)/2+\epsilon]$. So a small neighbourhood around $\log(5)/2$ is your burst.

Comment: @Balajisb I was thinking that $$ \begin{cases}
y'=y+y^3,\ t>0 \\
y(0)= \frac{1}{2}
\end{cases} $$ is a Bernoulli Equation.

Comment: Further in your derivation, you are assuming range of integration for $y(t)$ in the left hand side as $t$ varies from $0$ to $T$ is $[constant, y(T)]$. Is this correct ? It seems you  are assuming some monotonicity of $y(t)$ which is true after $5e^{-2t} < 1$

Comment: @Balajisb Yes that was my thought

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not get complex numbers in the final result of a real ODE. Your solution should be valid without restriction at $t=0$.

You could get faster to the result using the Bernoulli "trick" of dividing by the biggest power. Set $v=1+u^{-2}$, $v(0)=5$, then
$$
v'=-2u^{-3}u'=-2v\implies v(t)=e^{-2t}v(0),\\~\\
1+u(t)^{-2}=5e^{-2t},\\~\\
u(t)=\frac1{\sqrt{5e^{-2t}-1}},
$$
(positive square root as the initial value is positive).

The solution has a finite domain in the upper bound, the interval of definition ends at the pole where the denominator becomes zero.

Comment: +1 for the trick, but when $5 e^{-2t} < 1$, the solution is still complex ?

Comment: No, the solution ceases to exist at the pole $t=\ln(5)/2$. There is no coming back from infinity.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I tried to solve this problem as you advised me.

Answer (score 2):

We Solve the Bernoulli equation $\dfrac{dy(t)}{dt}-y(t)=  y(t)^3$ (1), such that $y(0) = \frac{1}{2}$.

We set $$v=y^{1-3}$$
Then we solve for y, which gives $$y=v^{-\frac{1}{2}}\,(2).$$
We differentiate the (2), so we have  that
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=-\frac{1}{2}v^{-\frac{3}{2}}\frac{dv}{dt}$$

We plug all those into equation (1) and we have
$$-\frac{1}{2}v^{-\frac{3}{2}}\frac{dv}{dt}-v^{-\frac{1}{2}}=(v^{-\frac{1}{2}})^3$$

We multiply both sides by $-2v^{\frac{3}{2}}$ and we received
$$\frac{dv}{dt}+2v=-2.$$

Let $$p(t)=e^{\int 2 dt}=e^{2t} $$

Multiply both sides with p(t) so we have:
$$\frac{dv}{dt}e^{2t}+e^{2t}2v=-2e^{2t}$$
We integrate
$$\int (e^{2t}v)' \, dt= \int -2 e^{2t} dt $$ and we have
$$e^{2t}v=-\frac{2e^{2t}v}{2}+c.$$ Then we solve for v
$$v=-1+c e^{-2t}.$$ Finally we solve for y and our solution is $$y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{-1+c e^{-2t}}}$$

Then we plug in  the initial condition $y(0) = \frac{1}{2}$ and we find that
$$y(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-1+5e^{-2 t } }}$$